# Ошибка "C2065: move: необъявленный идентификатор"

Tags: c++

Привет всем.

Создаю игру (первую) и вот ошибка.

```
// Unfit1.cpp: главный файл проекта.

#include <iostream>
int get_move()
{

    std::cout << "Move options : n " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "-7-|-8-|-9-" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "-4-|-5-|-6-" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "-1-|-2-|-3-" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "n";

    std::cout << "Game board:" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Your move: ";

    int move;
    std::cin >> move;
    while (move > 9 || move < 1) {
        std::cout << "Please enter a legal move (1-9)n You Move writte -> ";
        std::cin >> move;
    }
    return move;
}

int main()
{

    std::cout << "The move you entered is: " << move << std::endl;

    return 0;

}
```

> `1>  main.cpp
> 1>c:\users\cs\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\main\main\main.cpp(32): error C2065: move: необъявленный идентификатор`

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В функции `main` в строке

```
std::cout<<"The move you entered is: " << move << std::endl;
```

вместо `move` должен быть вызов функции `get_move`.

Comment: а куда дописать??(я Нуб В С++ консоль)

Comment: @Vlad234565 обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло.

Comment: примите ответ